# Zabbix web scenarios - how to include the content of the web response in notifications?

Tags: web, monitoring, zabbix, web-content

I have notifications coming back from web scenarios that say "PROBLEM' and "OK".  I would like to include the content of the web response when a problem happens.  I'm not worrying about header values, just the content of the web page.   Is this a variable I can reference in the Notification setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately zabbix doesn't store that data (the database would get rather huge). One thing you could do is add a media type script, which you send your alert to (instead of standard email). Then in that script you could parse the item that is triggering and do a separate curl on the webpage. Ugly and error-prone, but as good as it gets for now.

Comment: Is there a way to view the response Zabbix receives during a web scenario? we're having trouble debugging a step and we want to check the response to see if it is mangled in an unexpected way. 

I've tried using: $ server -R log_level_increase="http poller" but that didn't actually add the html response to the logs as the documentation would suggest.